# Join unique UserIDs with previous month' first time UserIDs

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I want to identify users that had a "first_open" event in month a (here: january) and came back to our in month b (here: february) with an "user_engagement" event.

My idea:
1. Create a table with all users who had a "first_open" event
2. Create a table with all users who had a "user_engagement" event
3. Join both tables on userID
4. Count Users who both had a "first_open" event in month a and month b and count all users from january with the "first_open" event

With the following query I am currently overcounting both the users in month a and b, because I am not counting all unqiue users for both event types.

```
    With
    users_first_open as (select 
    user_pseudo_id,
    EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) AS install_month,
    event_name as firstopen
    FROM
        `table.events_*`
    where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190101'
        AND '20190108' and event_name = "first_open" and 
        EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) = 1
    ),

    user_enagement_next_month as (select 
    user_pseudo_id,
    EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) AS engagement_month,
    event_name as engagament_next_month
    FROM
        `table.events_*`
    where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190109'
        AND '20190116' and event_name = "user_engagement"
        and EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) = 1), 

    cohort_raw as(
    select 
    user_pseudo_id,
    install_month,
    engagement_month, 
    case when firstopen = "first_open" then 1 else 0 end as cohort_count_first_open, 
    case when engagament_next_month = "user_engagement" then 1 else 0 end as cohort_count_engagement
    from 
    user_enagement_next_month
    full join 
    users_first_open using (user_pseudo_id))--, 


    select
    sum(case when cohort_count_first_open is not null then 1 else 0 end) as users_first_open,
    (select sum(case when cohort_count_engagement is not null then 1 else 0 end) as u_engagement_open from cohort_raw where cohort_count_first_open = 1) as users_engagement_open
    from cohort_raw
```

What I tried next was the following: group in table 2 "user_enagement_next_month" by userID, etc. 
and create a sum of "first_open" case when and "engagement" case when results. With the later I then included the query to only count users whose count of these two was = 2

  -

```
    With
    users_first_open as (select 
    user_pseudo_id,
    EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) AS install_month,
    event_name as firstopen
    FROM
        `table.events_*`
    where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190101'
        AND '20190131' and event_name = "first_open" and 
        EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) = 1
    ),

    user_enagement_next_month as (select 
    user_pseudo_id,
    EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) AS engagement_month,
    event_name as engagament_next_month
    FROM
        `table.events_*`
    where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190201'
        AND '20190228' and event_name = "session_start"
        and EXTRACT (Month FROM(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)))) = 2
        group by 1,2,3)--,

    --cohort_raw as(
    select 
    user_pseudo_id,
    install_month,
    engagement_month, 
    case when firstopen = "first_open" then 1 else 0 end as cohort_count_first_open, 
    case when engagament_next_month = "session_start" then 1 else 0 end as cohort_count_engagement
    --case when user_pseudo_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as cohort_count_engagement
    from 
    user_enagement_next_month 
    full join 
    users_first_open using (user_pseudo_id)), 

    cohort_agg as (
    select *, cohort_count_first_open+cohort_count_engagement as cohort_sum
    from cohort_raw
    group by 1,2,3,4,5
    order by 6 desc)

    select
    (select count(*) from users_first_open) as cohort_jan,
    (select Sum(cohort_sum) from cohort_agg where cohort_sum = 2) as ret, 
    sum(case when cohort_count_first_open is not null then 1 else 0 end) as users_first_open,
    (select sum(case when cohort_count_engagement is not null then 1 else 0 end) as u_engagement_open from cohort_raw where cohort_count_first_open = 1) as users_engagement_open
    from cohort_agg
```

I expect a return rate of around 20%. My output at the moment is 54%, because in my query I am either overcounting or counting to little, because I assume my join does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't clearly understand what you want, but try this one

```
with

users_first_open as (
    select distinct  -- is there duplicates for one user_id?
        user_pseudo_id,

        extract(
            month from
            timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)
        ) as install_month
    from
        `table.events_201901*`  -- longer prefixes generally perform better
    where
        _table_suffix between '01' and '31'
        and event_name = 'first_open'
        and extract(
                month from
                timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)
            ) = 1
),

user_enagement_next_month as (
    select distinct
        user_pseudo_id,

        extract(
            month from
            timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)
        ) as engagement_month
    from
        `table.events_201902*`  -- longer prefixes generally perform better
    where
        _table_suffix between '01' and '28'
        and event_name = 'user_engagement'
        and extract(
                month from
                timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)
            ) = 2
)

select 
    ufo.install_month,
    uenm.engagement_month,
    count(*) as first_open_event_users_cnt,
    count(uenm.user_pseudo_id) as user_engagement_event_users_cnt
from 
    users_first_open as ufo
    left join user_enagement_next_month as uenm
        on ufo.user_pseudo_id = uenm.user_pseudo_id
group by
    1, 2
```